# Missing selector such as '.identifier' or '[0]'. TapGestureRecognizer

Tags: flutter, dart, uitapgesturerecognizer

Code:

```dart
final tapRecognizer = TapGestureRecognizer()
    ..onTap!() = () =>
        AppGlobalFunctions().openExternalLink("https://xxxxxx.xxx");
```

Error log:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on Redmi Note 7 Pro in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
lib/modules/auth/phone_auth/phone_auth.dart:15:16: Error: Can't assign to this.
    ..onTap!() = () =>
               ^
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script '/Users/udit/Downloads/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 1201

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command '/Users/udit/Downloads/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

How to duplicate:

1. Create new flutter project
2. Copy `final tapRecognizer = TapGestureRecognizer() ..onTap!() = () => debugPrint("Hello world");` and paste code in _MyHomePageState
3. import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart' `import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';`
4. run project

Comment: You calling in wrong way, Please call in this manner          final tapRecognizer = TapGestureRecognizer()
                        ..onTap = () => debugPrint("Hello World");

Comment: Thanks, [vikas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6526994/vikas) [IIdeberto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14158791/ildeberto-vasconcelos)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you want to  assigning the  OpenExternaLink function to the tapRecognizer

so do it like this:

```
  final tapRecognizer = TapGestureRecognizer()
      ..onTap = () =>
          AppGlobalFunctions().openExternalLink("https://xxxxxx.xxx");
```

Answer (score 1):

**onTap** does not need function annotation (), remove () will make the code work

```
final tapRecognizer = TapGestureRecognizer() ..onTap = () => print("Message");
```